# Laravel Database in Real Practice

Tags: database, laravel

So, I have been wanting to ask about id in database. I want to make my own custom id format, but the problem is the id in laravel use auto increments, so, is it okay if in real practice I make my database has the auto increment id and my custom id, so it will be easier for making crud? Also, is there a way to reset the auto increment of id in database and make the id number matches with the counts of the data in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you saying "in real practice", but I strongly suggest that you stick to Laravel primary keys. Of course you can overwrite this config and work with your our keys, but in the end you'll be working double without any advantage. Let Laravel do the magic. The same goes with the id number matches with the counts of the data: the id is an internal number and you shouldn't care about that. However, you can reset the id and it will match with the counts:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: it's because when I delete a data from a table and insert a new data, the id of the new data won't match with the counts of the data. As for what I mean real practice is basically I mean for work. After all, most companies usually have their own id format for their products, that is what I am worried about

Comment: I've been working with my own company many years in real customers, with hundreds of companies. They can have their own id format of SKU but like @Zubair said, you better stick to official documentation, it's the best practice and the best solution "in real practice". I come from the old school and I had a hard time adapting to these new guidelines, but once you adopt them I assure you that you will not regret it. Go for it!

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest, don't touch the primary key in migration and create a new column with integer and name it as your custom primary key. Yes, you can do what you want in your real practice because the logic that you are developing for your understanding, client needs to be fulfilled but I also suggest you go for best practice. And best will come out from official documentation

Then in modal section, define the primary key to modal like

```
Modal {

  private $prmiary key = 'custom_id_column';

}
```